# Are Rvalue references optimized if passed along functions?

Tags: c++, c++11, pass-by-reference, rvalue-reference

I have the [simplified] code:

```
class AClass{
public:
    AClass( BigClass && bc ) : m_bc{std::move(bc)} {}

private:
    BigClass m_bc;
};

AClass * aFunction( BigClass && bc ){
    return new AClass( std::move(bc) );
}
```

It works. But Is it correct? The BigClass data is move along calls without creating temporaries?

Comment: I wasn't sure, I did'n known if I should use std::forward in the `aFucntion` but it fails.

Comment: std::forward is for templates.

Comment: All `std::move` does is change an lvalue to an rvalue. It doesn't actually do any moving.

Comment: `std::forward` is for [universal references](http://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Going+Deep/Cpp-and-Beyond-2012-Scott-Meyers-Universal-References-in-Cpp11), which are subtly different from rvalue references.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, what you have is correct.  You need to use `std::move` or the code won't compile.  It may not be immediately obvious why.  If we call your function like this:

```
AClass *a = aFunction(BigClass{});
```

`aFunction` is called with an rvalue, the return value from `BigClass`'s default constructor.  But inside `aFunction`, the variable `bc` is an **lvalue**.  Remember, if it has a name, it's an lvalue.  We have to turn `bc` into an rvalue with `std::move` in order to use `AClass`'s move constructor.

To see this more clearly, let's add some printouts (and a copy constructor) to `AClass`:

```
AClass( BigClass & bc ) : m_bc{bc} { std::cout << "Copy\n"; }
AClass( BigClass && bc ) : m_bc{std::move(bc)} { std::cout << "Move\n"; }
```

If you leave `std::move` out of `aFunction`, you'll get the copy.  With it, you'll get the move.

Comment: Thanks, I think that the key is "if it has a name, it's a lvalue" phrase :)